# On symmetric algebra of finite dimensional vector space and its dual

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, commutative-algebra

I am confused about the following argument which I can't disprove

We know that if $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb K$(algebraically closed,characteristic $0$) then symmetric algebra of $V$ is given by $S(V) = \mathbb K[x_1,....x_n]$,i.e a polynomial ring in $n$ indeterminates.In this situation we know that $V^*$ is also a finite dimensional vector space of dimension $n$ and hence $S(V^*) = \mathbb K[x_1,....x_n]$. Thus we have the following:

$\mathbb K[x_1,....x_n] = \oplus_{d \geq 0} (\mathbb K[x_1,....x_n])_d = \oplus_{d \geq 0} S^dV =\oplus_{d \geq 0} S^d(V^*) $, since the decomposition is unique we have $ (\mathbb K[x_1,....x_n])_d = S^dV = S^d(V^*), \forall d \geq 0 $

Now at this point I have the following questions(rather confusions):

$(1)$ In many sources it's said that $S(V^*)$ is the ring of polynomial functions on $V$ but $SV$ is not.But the above argument shows that both of them are the same.

$(2)$ Since we know that $S^d(V) = (\mathbb K[x_1,....x_n])_d$ and we can identify it with space of symmetric multilinear functionals on $V$,then we have space of symmetric multilinear functionals from $V \times V...\times V \to \mathbb K$($d$ copies)and from $V^* \times V^*...\times V^* \to \mathbb K$ ($d$ copies)are same.Is this true?

$(3)$ How to show that there exist a natural pairing $S^dV \otimes S^d(V^*) \to \mathbb K$(By the above argument $S^dV$ and $S^d(V^*)$ are same)

$(4)$ what does $(SV)^*$ look like?

I think I am missing some cardinal argument.Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: $S(V^*)$ is **not** equal to $\mathbb{K}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, which is where your confusion starts (it is isomorphic to that, but not equal to it since you've already given the $x_i$ a different meaning). If you want to fix generators of $S(V^*)$ a better choice would be $\mathbb{K}[x_1^*,\ldots,x_n^*]$ where the $x_i^*$ are the dual basis to the $x_i$.

Comment: @Matthew Towers ,In that case  can I say that $S^d(V^*) =$ homogeneous polynomial function(of degree $d$) over $V$.If so, then how can I say that $S^d(V^*) =$ space of homogeneous polynomials in $\mathbb P(V)$?,whereas we know that $S^d(V) =(\mathbb K[x_1,..x_n])_d =$ homogeneous polynomials over $\mathbb P(V)$(with $V \cong \mathbb K^n$). and what about the natural pairing?

Comment: For example, can I say that for $n=3$ and $d=2$ one can have as a result of natural pairing $(x_1.x_2+x_2.x_3) \otimes (x_1^*.x_2^*) |--->x_1^*(x_1.x_2+x_2.x_3).x_2^*(x_1.x_2+x_2.x_3)=0$(where while evaluating I am keeping it multiplicative and additive)

Comment: It seems like if we define the evaluation map by requiring to evaluate the entire thing in each of $x_1^*$ and $x_2^*$ and then apply bilinearity then it will be always zero unless the left hand side of the above tensor is possibly linear.So how to define the appropriate evaluation map in this case?